# How to remove an entity from the list and add a new one without violating unique constraint?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

These are my parent-child entities:

```
@Entity
public class Calculation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "calculation_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_standard_part"))
    private List<Part> parts;
}

@Entity
public class Part {
    @Column
    private String position;

    @Column
    private String positionDetail;
}
```

I'm using Hibernate and Spring Data:

1. I fetch Calculation from the database, the list of parts is populated.
2. There's a Part on the list with calculation_id=1, position='SIDE', position_detail='WINDOW'. I remove it from the list.
3. I create new Part with position='SIDE', position_detail='WINDOW' and I add it on the list.
4. I persist the Calculation using CrudRepository.save()
5. I get an error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uq_standard_operation" Detail: Key (calculation_id, "position", position_detail)=(1, 'SIDE', 'WINDOW') already exists.

Please advise what am I doing wrong. I don't want to update the Part entity if possible. It has many other attributes that may need to be cleared, hence I prefer replacing it. Thank you.

**EDIT 1:** Here is the piece of the code:

```
public Part repairStandardPart(Long calcId, String partNumber) {
    Part part = fetchNewPart(partNumber);
    Calculation calculation = getCalculation(calcId);
    // If there's a part with the same position allready I want to remove it...
    deletePartsAtPosition(calculation.getParts(), part.getPosition(), part.getSidePosition());
    // ...and then add the new one.
    calculation.getParts().add(part);
    calculationRepository.save(calculation);
    return part;
}

private void deletePartsAtPosition(List<Part> parts, String position, String positionDetail) {
    parts.removeIf(p -> Objects.equals(p.getPosition(), position) && Objects.equals(p.getPositionDetail(), positionDetail));
}
```

Comment: Try explicitly flushing the context after the item is removed: the delete should then happen before the insert.

Comment: Can you show your code that does what you list in the bullet points.

Comment: The relevant piece of code added...thanks!